# Linux home router can't route from new subnet to other internal subnet

Tags: linux, networking, router

I have a Linux router at home, which is a desktop machine with multiple nics and a wifi card.  This has been working great for a few years now. However I added a new interface (eth2) recently and can't access hosts on that network from the other internal networks.

```
eth0 - External interface to ISP

eth1 - Internal interface (172.16.0.1) Bcast:172.16.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth2 - The new network (172.16.48.1) Bcast:172.16.48.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

wlan0 - Wifi network (172.16.16.1)  Bcast:172.16.16.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

eth2 is the second port on a dual nic card (Intel 82546GB). eth1 is the first port on that card. eth0 is the builtin nic on the motherboard.  wlan0 is an Atheros AR5418 wifi card.

I have a simple firewall setup for now in order to troubleshoot the problem I'm having. Here is the firewall script:

```
#!/bin/bash

MYIP_EXT="myhomeip"
MYIP_INT="172.16.0.1"
EXT_INTERFACE="eth0"
INT_INTERFACE="eth1"
NEW_INTERFACE="eth2"
WIFI_INTERFACE="wlan0"

/sbin/iptables -F
/sbin/iptables -X
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -F
/sbin/iptables -t nat -F

/sbin/iptables -N droplog
/sbin/iptables -A droplog -s 0/0 -d 0/0 -j LOG --log-prefix "droplog "
/sbin/iptables -A droplog -s 0/0 -d 0/0 -j DROP

/sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXT_INTERFACE  -o $INT_INTERFACE -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i $INT_INTERFACE  -o $EXT_INTERFACE -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i $WIFI_INTERFACE -o $EXT_INTERFACE -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i $NEW_INTERFACE  -o $EXT_INTERFACE -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXT_INTERFACE -j SNAT --to $MYIP_EXT

/sbin/iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 2222 -i $EXT_INTERFACE -j DNAT --to 172.16.0.204:22

/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i $WIFI_INTERFACE -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i $INT_INTERFACE -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i $EXT_INTERFACE -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i $EXT_INTERFACE -j droplog
```

Router routing table:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         99.70.232.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
myhomeip.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.16.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
172.16.48.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
```

Everything works fine except that **I can't make connections from hosts on the 172.16.0.0/24 or 172.16.16.0/24 networks into the 172.16.48.0/24 networks on the new interface.**

I can connect from the router to hosts on the 172.16.48.0 network and from those hosts out to the internet. I can also connect between hosts on the 172.16.0.0 network and the 172.16.16.0 wifi network.

If I run tcpdump on the host 172.16.48.100 and try to ssh to it from 172.16.0.204 I see packets coming in, but not returning.

The network config on 172.16.48.100 is

```
inet addr:172.16.48.100  Bcast:172.16.48.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.48.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.48.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

If I run tcpdump on 172.16.0.204 and try to ssh from 172.16.48.100 to 172.16.0.204 I don't see any packets.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need iptables? Enable IP forwarding in the kernel.

Comment: @Nikolai Sorry, forgot to mention that. I have ip forwarding enabled in the kernel. I've been using this router for years now with this configuration. All I've added recently was the eth2 interface and new 172.16.48.0 network.

Comment: Do you have a DHCP server running on the router? Normally, on home routers you have a bridge interface and all LAN interfaces connected to it. you run the DHCP server on the bridge. And you configure NAT between bridge and WAN interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have an iptables rule

```
   /sbin/iptables -A droplog -s 0/0 -d 0/0 -j DROP
```

but you do **not** have the following rule:

```
   /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i $NEW_INTERFACE -j ACCEPT
```

Hence initial packet destined to $NEW_INTERFACE are dropped,and the connection never becomes ESTABLISHED,RELATED.

Comment: I thought INPUT in the sense of a router firewall means destined for the router itself. Adding the rule you mentioned does fix the problem though thanks.

Comment: @qhzonff No, INPUT refers to the interface: from one side to the other of the interface.

Comment: The iptables documentation seems to be different from your statement. From the --table option in the iptables man page: "INPUT (for packets destined to local sockets)" It also states in other places that INPUT implies packets that are destined for the server itself. Under COMPATIBILITY WITH IPCHAINS it says "The main difference is that the chains INPUT and OUTPUT are only traversed for packets coming into the local host and originating from the local host respectively." This is why I think that packets destined for other hosts don't touch the INPUT/OUTPUT chains.